# Manipulate presented timer in a psychopy experiment

Tags: python, psychopy

In the experiment, participants see an elapsed time display in the top right of the screen. My goal is to manipulate this display over different conditions.
In detail, in one condition, the elapsed timer should go by 1.2-time as fast, in another condition, only 0.8-time as fast as the real time. Of course, the timer should still display only full numbers (1,2,3 etc) without decimals. Whats a simple way to implement this?

I've tried adding or multiplying the timer with a constant, but this leads to a lot of decimals. If I were to round these numbers up or down, the timer would not be exact anymore, as each increase in the timer wouldn't necessarily equal to e.g. 1,2 seconds.

Comment: Run the timer faster (say each 10ms) but only show full seconds. This way you can multilply the speed of time elapsed without ruining the display.

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  Why does your delay time have to have anything to do with the displayed value?  Just set up a timer that does something every N seconds (.8, 1, 1.2, etc.), where that 'something' is to increment the display number by 1.

Comment: @Steve I assume they started with a fixed 1s timer and issues arrive from there.

Answer (score 1):

Create two PsychoPy text stimuli and a PsychoPy timer. In a loop, update the text stimuli with the current time value from the Clock object. This is just a time in seconds, starting from 0, so you can just multiply it by a constant to get the desired time dilation. e.g.

```
from psychopy import visual, event, core

win = visual.Window(units='height')
normal_text = visual.TextStim(win=win, pos=(0, 0.1))
faster_text = visual.TextStim(win=win, pos=(0, -0.1))

timer = core.Clock() # starts here at 0. Can be reset to 0 if needed.

# run until a key press:
while not event.getKeys():
    # update the time value:
    current_time = timer.getTime()

    normal_text.text = round(timer.getTime(), ndigits=1)
    faster_text.text = round(timer.getTime() * 1.2, ndigits=1)

    # display them on screen:
    normal_text.draw()
    faster_text.draw()
    win.flip()
```

You should see that when one text stimulus displays `12.0`, the other is still on `10.0`.

Re your issues with rounding, note that you can tell the rounding function to round to a specific number of decimal places, as above, but also you should do the multiplication before the rounding, or else the number of digits will indeed grow again.